# How do I bring back the "Lower" option when middle clicking on the title bar in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: 15.04

I've noticed after a fresh install of Linux 15.04 today that the lower option is no longer working. I really need this.

I've tried dconf-editor -> org -> gnome -> desktop -> wm -> preferences -> action-middle-click-titlebar but the "lower" option does not appear even though it is in the description.

Anyone have any suggestions. This is like the number one things I like for Ubuntu because it makes working so much faster not having to find my windows. I'm so frustrated already not being able to push my windows back.

Looking forward to any suggestions.

Comment: I've created a bug report for this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1448154 . You can click on the 'This bug affects you' link below the title to follow it.

Answer (score 6):

Okay awesome I figured it out for anyone else. Running this command updates the value and fixes it:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/action-middle-click-titlebar "'lower'"
```

Comment: does not work ubuntu 15.04 ... below answer does work :  unity-tweak-tool  -> Window Manager -> General -> Additional -> Titlebar Action -> Middle click ->  from list choose :  Lower

Answer (score 2):

This works with ubuntu 15.04  :

```
unity-tweak-tool  
-> Window Manager 
-> General 
-> Additional 
-> Titlebar Action -> Middle click 
->  from list choose :  Lower
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an option for this in the [Unity Tweak Tool](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/+package/unity-tweak-tool).

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

You can find the option in the Window-Manager section.